# How to Sort a list taking in account multiple factors?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, sql-order-by

I saw a ton of posts talking about OrderBy().ThenBy(), Sort(), IComparable, and that stuff. I couldn't manage to sort my list correctly though.

I need to sort a Recipe list a-z by the result (string) and if the Recipe is craftable. That would make craftable recipes be on top of the list sorted by alphabetical order and the non-craftable Recipes appear below also sorted by alphabetical order (the result is a string, the name of the item). Something like this:

Before:

- "arrow":craftable
- "boat":non-craftable
- "apple":non-craftable
- "box":craftable
- "can":craftable

After

- "arrow":craftable
- "box":craftable
- "can":craftable
- "apple":non-craftable
- "boat":non-craftable

That'd ensure the best result for my players.
This is roughly what the Recipe class looks like:

```
public class Recipe : ScriptableObject
{
    public Ingredient[] ingredients;

    public string result;
    public bool Craftable => //Not so complex and boring logic here;
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to do it currently:

```
Recipe[] recipes = _recipes.OrderBy(r => r.Craftable).ThenBy(r => r.result).ToArray();
```

That sorts a-z, but it doesn't separate craftables from non-craftables.

I'd be happy to know if there's already a question with an answer and if this ends up being a duplicate.

Also, I know that I could do that just by separating craftable Recipes from non-craftable ones in two distinct arrays and then sorting them a-z separately, but that'd be just boring. I want something better and more fun.

I'd love to know which is the most performant rout here because I can end up processing millions of recipes a second.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you show your attempt using `.OrderBy().ThenBy()`?

Comment: You can simply write your own comparison function for this.

Comment: @John yeah, not so much right now. Once I get back to my PC maybe. But it looks pretty much like Dmitry S solution, only swapping the x on ThenBy by r.

Comment: @AlKepp I'd like to see if there's any other options available before taking that route.

Comment: @MultipleGameStyles It doesn't actually mean what variable name you use in lambda in this case. You can use `r`, `x` or any other name. It just points to the instance of Recipe class.

Comment: @DmitryS I know xD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you do just like this?

```
var res = recipes.OrderBy(r => !r.Craftable).ThenBy(x => x.result);
```

**UPDATE:**

I tested my solution. Looks everything is OK:

```
var recipes = new List<Recipe>
{
    new Recipe { result = "arrow", Craftable = true},
    new Recipe { result = "boat", Craftable = false},
    new Recipe { result = "apple", Craftable = false},
    new Recipe { result = "can", Craftable = true},
    new Recipe { result = "box", Craftable = true}

};

var res = recipes.OrderBy(r => !r.Craftable).ThenBy(x => x.result);  
// note !r.Craftable in OrderBy clause, it means we first take craftable
```

You can also make it work the following way. It outputs the same result:

```
var res = recipes.OrderByDescending(r => r.Craftable).ThenBy(x => x.result);
// false = 0, true = 1, so we sort Craftable by descending, first 1 (Craftable = true), then 0 (Craftable = false)
```

This gives me the following result:

- arrow True
- box   True
- can   True
- apple False
- boat  False

Comment: Because that only returns me a list sorted a-z, weirdly. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Multiple Can you update your answer and show how you do it?

Comment: @Multiple [example with Dmitry's code](https://rextester.com/GJAW39900) - looks exactly like your desired sort order.

Comment: @DmitryS Updated!

Comment: @Aldert it wasn't in the question when he first answered.

Comment: I took my comment out, confusing when questions get updated :-)

Comment: @DmitryS By my mistake it wouldn't sort the Recipes. I was sorting only once when the player had no items in their inventory by mistake. I took a few hours for me to realize that, but I found the bug. You see, it's hard to maintain a ball of mud code. Thanks for your help, and I'm sorry if I've caused any inconvenience with my mistakes. :)

Comment: @MultipleGameStyles no problem, glad to help